# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: referenceerror

i have an error when i try to make a point of sales

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

here's my code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "proses.php",
    data: "op=simpanpembelian&idpembelian=" + idpembelian + "&idbarangpembelian=" + idbarangpembelian + "&tgl=" + tgl + "&namabarangpembelian=" + namabarangpembelian + "&kemasan=" + kemasan + "&jumlah=" + jumlah + "&harga=" + harga + "&isi=" + isi = "&total=" + total,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == "sukses") {
            $("#status").html("Data berhasil disimpan. . .");
        } else {
            $("#status").html("Error");
        }
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#tgl").val("");
        $("#idpembelian").val("");
        $("#idbarangpembelian").val("");
        $("#namabarangpembelian").val("");
        $("#kemasan").val("");
        $("#jumlah").val("");
        $("#harga").val("");
        $("#isi").val("");
        $("#total").val("");
        $("#pembelian").load("proses.php", "op=pembelian");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo here:

```
"&isi=" + isi = "
```

`=` should be `+`

```
harga + "&isi=" + isi + "&total=" + total,
```